# How do I disable the "octave:#>" echo?

Tags: octave

Octave shows echo "octave:#>" before command line in interactive mode where # is the order of the entry. I want to use a program that uses it so I want to cancel that echo. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [command prompt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt). You can set the `PS1` to the empty string with:

```
PS1("")
```

For more info: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Customizing-the-Prompt.html